# Swift: trouble with Arrays of classes

Tags: arrays, swift, core-graphics

I'm trying to create an array of two items: a URL and a String. The index of the items is of significance.

The data is taken from QuartzFilterManager, which provides information about the Quartz Filters installed on a system.

```
import Cocoa
import Quartz

class myFilter {
    var myURL: URL?
    var name: String = ""
}

func getFilters() -> Array<String> {
    var filterArray: Array<myFilter>
    if let Filters = QuartzFilterManager.filters(inDomains: nil) {

        for (index, eachFilter) in Filters.enumerated() {
            filterArray[index].name.append((eachFilter as! QuartzFilter).localizedName()!)
            filterArray[index].myURL!.append((eachFilter as! QuartzFilter).url()!)
            }
    }
}
```

Xcode complains about Type URL not having an append method. But the name property in the preceding line works. In short, how do I set specific properties in my array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of issues.

1. Make `myFilter` a struct instead of class and name it properly as `MyFilter`.
2. You never initialize your `filterArray`, you only declare it.
3. You need to create a new instance of `MyFilter` for each url/name pair you want to add to the array.
4. You don't need to use `enumerated` in this case.
5. You have the wrong return type for your `getFilter` function (I think).
6. Use proper naming conventions.

Here's cleaned up code:

```
struct MyFilter {
    var myURL: URL?
    var name: String
}

func getFilters() -> [MyFilter] {
    var filterArray = [MyFilter]()
    if let filters = QuartzFilterManager.filters(inDomains: nil) {
        for eachFilter in filters {
            let filter = MyFilter(myURL: (eachFilter as! QuartzFilter).url(), name: (eachFilter as! QuartzFilter).localizedName()!)
            filterArray.append(filter)
        }
    }

    return filterArray
}
```

It's still not ideal. Having to cast `eachFilter` using `as! QuartzFilter` is clunky.

And other uses of `!` are bad. Force-unwrapping the call to `localizedName()` can crash. Consider proper solutions.

Comment: Thanks. That's broadly working. Can you clarify why the uses of ! are bad and what "proper solutions" might be? Surely I need to unwrap at some point, to get something that's not an optional?

Comment: If I don't cast eachFilter, then I just get an Any type, and the methods don't work.

Comment: Yes, safely unwrap instead of using `!`. And `eachFilter` should already be a `QuartzFilter`. The fact they you need the cast means that `QuartzFilterManager.filters(inDomains: nil)` isn't returning a very well defined type.

Answer (score 1):

Append is a method of the array struct, not of the URL/String.

1. You first need to create the array (you just declared it, you actually need to assign something to it)
2. You then need to create the object that you want to append into the array
3. You can now append this newly created object to the array

It should look something like this:

```
import Cocoa
import Quartz

class MyFilter {
    var myURL: URL?
    var name: String?

    init(url: URL?, name: String?) {
        self.myURL = url
        self.name = name
    }
}

func getFilters() -> Array<MyFilter> {
    var filterArray = [MyFilter]()
    if let filters = QuartzFilterManager.filters(inDomains: nil) {

        for filter in filters {
            let aFilter = MyFilter(url: filter.url(), name: filter.localizedName())
            filterArray.append(aFilter)
        }
    }
    return filterArray
}
```

Now the array returned by this method will have N MyFilter objects.
You can access every object in the array the way you did before, with

```
let aFilter = filterArray[index]
```

And to get the property inside of that object:

```
let url = aFilter.myURL
let name = aFilter.name
```

PS: I changed some names to fit the swift conventions (classes are written in **PascalCase** and variables in **camelCase**)

PpS: be careful with **!** in swift, if it's used on something that happens to be nil will crash the app. Read more about optionals [here](https://learnappmaking.com/swift-optionals-how-to/)

PpPs: I was just a few minutes late :D

Comment: I get "Value of optional type 'String?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'String'" in the init, but there's some good stuff here.

Comment: Yes @benwiggy, I forgot to edit the name variable as optional.